VSCode SQLTools gives unnecessary errors for non-keywords as keywords
VSCode SQLTools gives unnecessary errors for non-keywords as keywords such as position, name, password, etc.
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS VolleyDB;
CREATE DATABASE VolleyDB;
USE VolleyDB;

CREATE TABLE Player 
(
    username    VARCHAR(512),
    password    VARCHAR(512),
    name    VARCHAR(512),
    surname VARCHAR(512),
    date_of_birth   VARCHAR(512),
    height  INT,
    weight  INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE PlayerPositions 
(
    player_positions_id INT,
    username    VARCHAR(512),
    position    INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (player_positions_id)
);

CREATE TABLE PlayerTeams 
(
    player_teams_id INT,
    username    VARCHAR(512),
    team    INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (player_teams_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Team 
(
    team_ID INT,
    team_name   VARCHAR(512),
    coach_username  VARCHAR(512),
    contract_start  VARCHAR(512),
    contract_finish VARCHAR(512),
    channel_ID  INT,
    channel_name    VARCHAR(512),
    PRIMARY KEY (team_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Coach 
(
    username    VARCHAR(512),
    password    VARCHAR(512),
    name    VARCHAR(512),
    surname VARCHAR(512),
    nationality VARCHAR(512),
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE Position
(
    position_ID INT,
    position_name   VARCHAR(512),
    PRIMARY KEY (position_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Jury 
(
    username    VARCHAR(512),
    password    VARCHAR(512),
    name    VARCHAR(512),
    surname VARCHAR(512),
    nationality VARCHAR(512),
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE MatchSession 
(
    session_ID  INT,
    team_ID INT,
    stadium_ID  INT,
    stadium_name    VARCHAR(512),
    stadium_country VARCHAR(512),
    time_slot   INT,
    date    VARCHAR(512),
    assigned_jury_username  VARCHAR(512),
    rating  DOUBLE,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE SessionSquads 
(
    squad_ID    INT,
    session_ID  INT,
    played_player_username  VARCHAR(512),
    position_ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (squad_ID)
);

This gives an error as

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Position
(
position_ID INT,
position_name   VARCHAR(512),
PRIMARY KEY ' at line 1"


I tested using SQLTools and then I tested the same code in the mysql command-line client. It works in the command-line client, but I get the same error you do in SQLTools.
I ran SELECT @@sql_mode; in SQLTools and in the client to compare:
SQLTools:

IGNORE_SPACE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

mysql:

ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

It seems like SQLTools adds IGNORE_SPACE to the SQL mode for some reason. I don't know how this is happening. I don't have that SQL mode configured on my local instance. I downloaded the source for SQLTools from github, but I don't find any reference to sql_mode or IGNORE_SPACE in that repo.
The effect of this is that POSITION (...) is interpreted the same as POSITION(...), which means it conflicts with the built-in function POSITION().
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space

IGNORE_SPACE
Permit spaces between a function name and the ( character. This causes built-in function names to be treated as reserved words. As a result, identifiers that are the same as function names must be quoted as described in Section 11.2, “Schema Object Names”.

You can work around this by putting the table name in back-ticks. This allows you to use any reserved keyword as an identifier, and likewise words that conflict with built-in functions.
CREATE TABLE `Position`
(
    position_ID INT,
    position_name   VARCHAR(512),
    PRIMARY KEY (position_ID)
);

There might be a way to override the SQL mode of the MySQL SQLTools driver, but I don't know.
